# Regex for coercing input for phone number in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, directive

I have an input for a phone number in french format
The input accepts two kinds of format, so i can input this:

1. 0699999999
2. +33699999999

no check is done for the length of the number.

The table in database, the field is of varchar 12, i can have shorter input though.
The constraints: input contains only digits from 0 to 9, optional '+' sign accepted only if it starts the string, not after.

Currently i am in Angular with a directive, in that directive the heart is this expression :

```
var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

i want the optional leading '+' sign, how can i achieve this?
thanks.

Comment: regex only? it might be simpler to check for `+` before applying the regex and add it later again

Comment: i didn't write the directive and was looking for a similar solution, regex are powerful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9\+]/g, '').replace(/(.)\+/g, '$1');
```

Note - this will NOT add a + unless there is already a + in the input

---

What it does is

1. Do not remove the + symbol on the first replace
2. Remove every + symbol that is preceded by some character on the 2nd replace

Comment: thanks this worked for me, also to note: since i am using angular, white space is authorized in the input despite regex, unless you add ng-trim="false"

Answer (score 2):

You could make the plus sign optional:

```
if (/\+?\d*/.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

subject is the text you want to check. \+ makes the plus sign a literal and the questionmark makes it optional.

If you just want to check wether ther is a plussign drop the questionmark. But if that is your goal don't use a regex. That is too much overhead. Simply get the first charactor of the trimmed string and check for the plus.